# AlertDialog из onPostExecute сервиса

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

Доброе время суток.

Как сделать вызов алерта из сервиса? Toast-уведомление работает, а вот алерт ([пример отсюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/alertdialog.php)) вываливается с ошибкой **java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.**

При чём тут тема? Из MainActivity, кстати, нормально работает.
Ну или другой способ показать уведомление что задача завершена (только если MainActivity сейчас на экране).

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Диалог - это неполноэкранная активити и для отображения виджетов в диалоге нужна какая-то тема, как эти виджеты должны выглядеть, в вашем случае - конкретная тема из библиотеки поддержки AppCompat.   Какая тема у вас в манифесте назначена для всего приложения (в секции <application>), от какого класса наследуется ваша `MainActivity` и как вы вызываете диалог в этой активити?

Comment: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`
Диалог (пытался) вызвать не в активити, а в **onPostExecute**.

Comment: Нашёл ответ - [получаем из сервиса результат с помощью BroadcastReceiver](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/161-urok-96-service-obratnaja-svjaz-s-pomoschju-broadcastreceiver.html)

Правда остаётся вопрос при чём тут ошибка связанная с темой.